# Value Error : The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

```
def answer_three():
    if(df['Gold.2']>=1):
      return df[df['diff']/df['Gold.2'].max()].index[0]
answer_three()
```

By writing this code I got an error like this

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool()....

where diff is:

```
df['diff'] = abs(df['Gold'] - df['Gold.1'])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to compare a Serie (df['Gold.2']) with a number, basically what Python is seeing is something similar to this: `[0 4 6 7 4 2 0 4] >= 1` and returning `[False True True True True True False True]`.

So when you try to check `if [False True True True True True False True]` python doesn't know what to do and ask you to use one of `any, empty, all, etc` methods that make this list to flatten into one.

If you can explain what is exactly what you want I could help you to also fix the code.

Comment: there are actually two columns and I have to find Which country had the biggest difference between their summer and winter gold medal counts? from a github profile I got an ans like this 
   def answer_three():
    
    sub_df = df[(df['Gold'] > 0) & (df['Gold.1'] > 0)].copy()
    sub_df['rel'] = sub_df['diff'] / sub_df['Gold.2']
    return sub_df[sub_df['rel'] == max(sub_df['rel'])].index[0]

answer_three()